# BigQuery SQL / GIS: Extend Radius Until Count Is Greater Than / Equal To 'N'

Tags: google-bigquery, postgis

I have a very special kind of query to write. In PostGIS / BigQuery, I have a `point`. I can buffer this point by increments and perform an aggregation query, such as `count(distinct())` on the unique records that fall within this point. Once the count reaches a certain threshold, I would like to return the input value of the geographic object, ie. its radius or diameter. This problem can be phrased as *"how far do I have to keep going out until I hit 'n' [ids]?"*.

Finely incrementing the value of the buffer or radius will be insufferably slow and expensive. Can anyone think of a nice way to short this and offer a solution that provides a nice answer quickly (in BQ or PSQL terms!)?

**Available GIS functions:**

`st_buffer()`
`st_dwithin()`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You would have to order by distance and keep the N closest points. The [`<->`](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_distance_knn.html) operator will use the spatial index.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM pointLayer p
ORDER BY p.geometry <-> st_makePoint(...)
LIMIT 10; --N
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to increment radius *finely* - I would rather double it, or maybe even increment 10x and once you have enough distinct records, take N nearest ones.

I've used BigQuery scripting to solve similar problem (with N=1, but it is easy to modify for any N, just use `LIMIT N` instead of `LIMIT 1` and modify stopping condition):
https://medium.com/@mentin/nearest-neighbor-using-bq-scripting-373241f5b2f5